# How to add multiple values in single column

Tags: sql, database-design, definition, create-table

I am designing a SQL table structure as:

```
 CREATE TABLE InCollection (
       author NVARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
       title TEXT,
       year INT DEFAULT '0',
       booktitle TEXT )
```

Now column 'author' may have a single value or multiple tags as

```
<author></author>
```

or

```
<author></author><author></author><author></author>
```

So how to define this column in table structure, so I would be able to insert single value or multiple value in 'author' when found multiple values.

Comment: You mean how to insert multiple rows when found multiple values?

Comment: Your design is not a good match for RDBMS. You need two more tables to express what you are looking for. Books with multiple authors is a classic example for RDBMS designs, so you can find many tutorials discussing specifically this case. Here is one example: [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/relational-databases-defining-relationships-between-database-tables/).

Comment: The data type `TEXT` is deprecated and will be removed from future versions of SQL Server, you should use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead. Storing multiple values in a single column has never been a good idea and never will be. You should give your book table a primary key, create a new table to store authors and link back to your book using a foreign key. Although you will need to do a JOIN to retrieve your author(s), it will make it much more searchable than using XML, or any other delimited string.

Comment: Sometimes, having a database model that specfies a single field with multiple values merely signals a bad design.  Consider refactoring your data specification.  The usual  way to do this is to create a new table with a foreign key relationship to the table that originally contained the multiple valiues.  Some RDBMS systems support array values for fields (part of the SQL specification but not univerally supported).  Otherwise, you're left with parsing the string into an array or another similar approach ... which can get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple values to a single column by appending the values with some symbol like ",".
While getting the values from user interface combine or join them with "," make the values as a single string and then pass the value to the column.